# CSS Layout (many different size layers filling space)

Tags: css, layout, html, xhtml, css-float

How to achieve a result, when there is a big space and I want to fill it completely with layers one close to each other. All of them are of same width and they should divide into 4 columns.
Sample (tried to float all the layers and this is, what I get):
http://img98.imageshack.us/f/layoutjp.png/

What to do with the layers to make them all fill the space without leaving white spaces in between?
Open for any ideas,
Thanks,
Jonas

Comment: Sometimes tables really are the best answer, semantics be damned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [jQuery Masonry](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/) plug-in.

Comment: That is amazing. Thanks for mentioning that, now I have a new tool for my belt.